# Find the condition on the real numbers $a,b$ and $c$ such that the following system of equations has a solution:

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the condition on the real numbers $a,b$ and $c$ such that the following system of equations has a solution:
$2x+y+3z=a$
$x+z=b$
$y+z=c$

After calculation I get $a-2b-c=0$ will be the answer. Can anybody please confirm me please that I am correct or not.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Answer (score 2):

*This CW answer intends to remove this question from the Unanswered queue.*

---

You are correct (as already noted in the comments).